# Where in the C++ Standard does it document I/O of user-defined types?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++14

I looked into N4140 for something like this, but couldn't find it:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& obj)
{
  // write obj to stream
  return os;
}
```

Shouldn't this be documented in the Standard?

Comment: It is a normal operator overloading of `<<`, which is described in §13.5 [over.oper], I'm not sure if that's the documentation you want.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're looking for? There is no standard-library-provided overload for user-defined types, and users can create their own overloads through normal operator overloading.

Comment: @KennyTM As far as I can understand the specific use of the left shift operator for the output of a user-defined type should be documented in the Standard.

Comment: The standard describes what is logically possible to do. Since the ability of left-shift to output user-defined types is logically implied by the standard, it _is_ documented by the standard to the extent it should be. The standard exists to tell compiler-developers what features they must implement and to tell you what you can expect those essential features to be; it is not intended to teach you how to program.

Comment: It is unclear why you think the standard should do that. There is no requirement that output of user-defined types shall be done with `operator<<`.

Comment: @DavidK `Since the ability of left-shift to output user-defined types is logically implied by the standard` - Could you tell me where can I find this implication in the Standard?

Comment: "Logically implied by," _not_ "explicitly described by." The Peano postulates define the natural numbers and _logically imply_ that 2+2=4, but the equation "2+2=4" is not written in the Peano postulates. The essence of a logical implication is that it is something that you can deduce from the given information without someone having to tell you everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's all the evidence I could find on the matter (quoting N4140):

**13.5**

> 1 A function declaration having one of the following *operator-function-ids* as its name declares an *operator function.* A function template declaration having one of the following *operator-function-ids* as its name declares an *operator function template.* A specialization of an operator function template is also an operator function. An operator function is said to *implement* the operator named in its *operator-function-id.*
>
> *operator-function-id:*
>
> `operator` *operator*
>
> *operator:* one of
>
> ```
>  new delete new[] delete[]
>  + - * / % ˆ & | ~
>  ! = < > += -= *= /= %=
>  ˆ= &= |= << >> >>= <<= == !=
>  <= >= && || ++ -- , ->* ->
>  ( ) [ ]
> ```
>
> [ *Note:* The last two operators are function call (5.2.2) and subscripting (5.2.1). The operators `new[]`, `delete[]`, `()`, and `[]` are formed from more than one token. *—end note* ]
>
> 6 An operator function shall either be a non-static member function or be a non-member function that has
>   at least one parameter whose type is a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to an
>   enumeration. ...

**13.5.2**

> 1 A binary operator shall be implemented either by a non-static member function (9.3) with one parameter
>   or by a non-member function with two parameters. Thus, for any binary operator `@`, `x@y` can be interpreted
>   as either `x.operator@(y)` or `operator@(x,y)`. If both forms of the operator function have been declared,
>   the rules in 13.3.1.2 determine which, if any, interpretation is used.

Nowhere does the standard prohibit specifying classes from `std` as parameter types of operator functions (or any functions, for that matter).

Notice the presence of `<<` and `>>` in the table in 13.5/1. These imply it's legal to overload `operator <<` for any two types where at least one conforms to the conditions listed in 13.5/6. `std::ostream` is a typedef for `std::basic_ostream<char>`, which is a class. So overloading `operator<< (std::ostream&, T)` is valid for any type `T`.

That's all the standard has to say about it. There are no special rules for overloading `<<` to mean stream insertion—there don't *have to* be. It's just normal application of operator overloading. If you really wanted, you could overload `%` for that purpose instead.

The only other places in the standard which touch on `<<` with streams I can think of are:

- 27.7.3.9/1, the `operator<<` overload for rvalue reference to output streams, which lists its effect as:

  > 1 *Effects:* `os << x`

  So if you overload `<<` for your class, the standard library inserter for output stream rvalues will invoke it for your class.
- Stream iterators (24.6). For example, 24.6.2/1 says that:

  > 1 `ostream_iterator` writes (using `operator<<`) successive elements onto the output stream from which it
  >   was constructed. ...

Comment: Good write-up. But I can't see anything in it that would allow me to deduce  the construction posted on my question to output a user-defined type. For instance, there is no statement in your answer regarding the use of the left shift operator to output a user-defined time, the same way you can find in Chapter 27 for the built-in types.

Comment: @Ayrosa Yes, there is. It says that you can overload `<<` for a stream and a user-defined type to do *whatever you want,* including writing that user-defined type to the stream *somehow*. I don't understand what your problem is. If you want to output a user-defined type to a stream using `<<`, you have to overload `<<` for a stream type and that user-defined type, and implement the writing in that operator function.

Comment: `including writing that user-defined type to the stream somehow` Where does it say so? I know I'm being pedantic here. But assume the following hypothetical situation: a programmer **who has never read a book on C++** decides to output a user-defined type. Do you really believe he would be able to accomplish this, just by reading the Standard? I doubt it.

Comment: @Ayrosa it's a standard not a tutorial

Comment: @Ayrosa Why on Earth is a programmer reading the standard before a book?!? The standard is *not* learning material. You're *not* supposed to learn the language by reading the standard. Notice it doesn't say how you implement a tree, either. Or radix sort. That's not what it's for. But to play along: it tells you how to access members, how to overload operators, and that `<<` is overloaded for primitive types. That's all you really need to do a member-wise output of a UDT, for example.

Comment: @Angew `Why on Earth is a programmer reading the standard before a book?!?`That's why I mentioned the term **hypothetical**. Of course nobody would dare to do that. But what I'm trying to say is that the Standard has to define everything you can do with the language or at least allow you to deduce other results, from what it's already in there. I'm sorry, but I haven't seen any of this, in the arguments presented so far.

Comment: @Angew With regard to your comment above: `It says that you can overload << for a stream and a user-defined type to do whatever you want` I repeat my question: where can I find this? If you show me this or something similar in the Standard, I can accept your answer.

Comment: @Ayrosa You can overload `<<` for *any* two types as long as at least one of them conforms to 13.5/6 (class, class reference, enumeration, enumeration reference). `std::basis_ostream<char>` *is a class.* The UDT is a class as well. What more do you need?

Comment: @Angew I finally understood what you meant. (+1)